# C# Normal Random Number

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, statistics, random

I would like to create a function that accepts `Double mean`, `Double deviation` and returns a random number with a normal distribution.

Example: if I pass in 5.00 as the mean and 2.00 as the deviation, 68% of the time I will get a number between 3.00 and 7.00

My statistics is a little weak…. Anyone have an idea how I should approach this?  My implementation will be C# 2.0 but feel free to answer in your language of choice as long as the math functions are standard.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197321/need-help-generating-discrete-random-numbers-from-distribution/1197393#1197393) might actually be what I am looking for.  Any help converting this to code?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks everyone who has posted so far.  You are pointing me in the right direction.  I did not realize this was such a complex task.  I was pretty sure someone would cough up a 4 liner in no time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables

Comment: Using the [MedallionRandom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MedallionRandom) package, you can do this with `mean + (random.NextGaussian() * deviation)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See this CodeProject article: [Simple Random Number Generation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/SimpleRNG.aspx). The code is very short, and it generates samples from uniform, normal, and exponential distributions.

Comment: +1  I think this may be exactly what I am looking for!  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this perfect.  Not too long and does exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: Simple it is and works great. good job!

Answer (score 12):

You might be interested in [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/About.aspx), specifically the Numerics package.

**Caveat**: The numerics package targets .NET 3.5.  You may need to use the Iridium package if you are targeting an earlier version...

Comment: Looking at the feature at http://www.mathdotnet.com/doc/IridiumFeatures.ashx now... Not quite sure which function I want.  Maybe one of the Continuous Probability Distributions?  I might just have to download the source and pour over the code tonight.

Comment: You want to use MathNet.Numerics.Distributions, and do something like that, which will draw from a Normal with mean 5.0 and sigma 0.68:
         var mu = 5.00;
         var sigma = 0.68;
         var normal = new NormalDistribution(mu, sigma);
         var draw = normal.NextDouble();

Answer (score 8):

Here is some C that returns two values (rand1 and rand2), just because the algorithm efficiently does so.  It is the polar form of the [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).

```
void RandVal (double mean1, double sigma1, double *rand1, double mean2, double sigma2, double *rand2)
{
double u1, u2, v1, v2, s, z1, z2;

do {
    u1 = Random (0., 1.);  // a uniform random number from 0 to 1
    u2 = Random (0., 1.);
    v1 = 2.*u1 - 1.;
    v2 = 2.*u2 - 1.;
    s = v1*v1 + v2*v2;
} while (s > 1. || s==0.); 

z1 = sqrt (-2.*log(s)/s)*v1;
z2 = sqrt (-2.*log(s)/s)*v2;
*rand1 = (z1*sigma1 + mean1);
*rand2 = (z2*sigma2 + mean2);
return;
```

}

Comment: It would be helpful if you named your variables something other than "u", "v", etc., for example, mean and sigma are very helpful.

Comment: The variables u, v, z, and s are used to maintain consistency with the customary mathematical notation used in the Box-Muller transform.

Comment: As a tutor I can attest that it would have been helpful for most people if the customary mathematical notations themselves had been labeled more descriptively.

Answer (score 5):

This library is pretty good also:

[.NET random number generators and distributions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Random.aspx)

Comment: +1  This looks promising.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have any code for you but I can point you to [some algorithms on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution). The algorithm you choose I guess depends on how accurate you want it and how fast it needs to be.

Comment: +1  This looks good too.  How do I create the "two independent random numbers U and V uniformly distributed on (0, 1]"?  Sorry... I told you my stats are weak.

Comment: In C# you would use the "Random" class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx). Specifically the method NextDouble returns a uniformly distributed number in the range of 0 to 1. Uniformly distributed just means that you have an equal chance of getting any of the numbers in the range, there is no bias towards any specific number.

Answer (score 1):

For those referencing this question, an easy solution might be:

```
Random rand = new Random();
double normRand  = alglib.invnormaldistribution(rand.NextDouble())
```

scale by mu and sigma as needed.
The alglib library is available at [www.alglib.net](http://www.alglib.net)

Answer (score 1):

### MathNet

from second top answer

```
    public static double GenerateRandomVariant(double mean,double deviation,System.Random rand=null, int factor=1)
    {

        rand = rand ?? new Random();
        double randNormal=(MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal.Sample(rand, mean , deviation));
        return factor * randNormal;

    }
```

### Box-Mueller Transform

from top answer via link (twice as fast?)

by u/yoyoyoyosef [Random Gaussian Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables)

```
    public static double GenerateRandomVariant(double mean, double deviation, System.Random rand=null, int factor = 1)
    {
        rand = rand ?? new Random();
        double u1 = 1.0 - rand.NextDouble(); //uniform(0,1] random doubles
        double u2 = 1.0 - rand.NextDouble();
        double randStdNormal = Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(u1)) *
                     Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * u2); //random normal(0,1)
        double randNormal=(
                     mean +  deviation * randStdNormal); //random normal(mean,stdDev^2)
        return randNormal * factor;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MetaNumerics](http://www.meta-numerics.net/) library, also .NET, will calculate a normal distribution (and just about anything else from statistics), super quickly. Have a look at the Feature's page for more details. The Codeplex page is here: http://metanumerics.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little old but I would like to share a small project I created yesterday.
I think the easier way is to use C++ 11 and create a .dll in Managed C++.
There's a [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-9-aNtFfwn8Y0p3d1otN1VDQTQ&usp=sharing) to the source and a zip containing the dll already compiled.

And the code I made :

```
// NormalDistributionRandom.h
#include <random>

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace NormalDistribution 
{

    class _NormalDistributionRandom
    {
        std::default_random_engine engine;
        std::normal_distribution<double> distribution;

    public:
        _NormalDistributionRandom(double mean, double deviation) : distribution(mean, deviation)
        {
        }

        double Next()
        {
            return distribution(engine);
        }
    };

    public ref class NormalDistributionRandom
    {
    private:

        void* Distribution;

    public:

        NormalDistributionRandom( double mean, double deviation)
        {
            Distribution = new _NormalDistributionRandom(mean, deviation);
        }

        double Next()
        {
            return ((_NormalDistributionRandom*)Distribution)->Next();
        }
        ~NormalDistributionRandom()
        {
            this->!NormalDistributionRandom();
        }
    protected:
        !NormalDistributionRandom()
        {
            if (Distribution != nullptr)
            {
                delete (_NormalDistributionRandom*)Distribution;
                Distribution = nullptr;
            }
        }
    };

}
```