# library for random number generation

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Normal Random Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626023/c-normal-random-number)

Can anyone suggest me on what kind of libraries we can use for random number generation woth Gaussian or uniform distribution like in matlab in C#

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend this project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Random.aspx It contains these random number generator algorithms:

1. Additive Lagged Fibonacci
2. Mersenne Twister
3. A "standard" generator based on System.Random
4. xorshift

It contains quite a few  continuous and discrete distributions as well.