# PHP: Random number from a normal distribution

Tags: php, random, statistics, normal-distribution

In `PHP`, can I get a set of *random numbers* which conform to a specified **mean** and **standard deviation**?

Comment: From what type of distribution? Uniform? Normal? Something else?

Comment: Choose a distribution first. There are an infinite number of ways that  a set of numbers can conform to those criterion.

Comment: Great points, I missed a detail, normal is normal enough for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`stats_rand_gen_normal`](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.stats-rand-gen-normal.htm) function will do exactly this. (Assuming you mean a normal distribution.)

Comment: Well, had to manually patch it before compile to make it work (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57830), and now it just generates the same number each time I call it (the arch-nemesis of randomness, complete predictability). Any idea how this thing works? There are no docs.

Comment: @DavidParks: There are several questions here that discuss how a function like that works on this page's sidebar, for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626023/c-sharp-normal-random-number).

Comment: @DavidParks Show the part of your code that calls [`srand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php). Your bug is likely there.